# Setting up two APs with switch inbetween (same subnet)

Tags: networking, lan, dhcp, wireless-access-point, switch

My ideal setup for home network is presented on the image. 192.168.55.1 has DHCP on, while 192.168.55.2 and .3 act as APs with DHCP off to extend my WiFi. I wanted to connect a device in between 192.168.55.2 and 192.168.55.1, so I added a switch (can't connect directly to .1 due to lack of ports and .2 is too far). However, now this device is not able to ping 192.168.55.3 and I have some IP conflicts inbetween different device in my subnet. What is the problem here?

Also, DHCP range configured on .1 is 192.168.55.100 - 192.168.55.252.

[Network setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvSI1.png)

Comment: What are the switch and AP models? Have you tested the switch using wired computers in place of APs?

Comment: Switch is a simple, cheap TP-link 5 port unmanaged switch (TL-SG105) and for APs, both are TP Link AC1200 routers setup in AP mode. 192.168.55.1 is main router (Dasan) provided by my ISP.

Comment: Oh, actually I was browsing my .1 router settings and found that Port Bridge option was disabled between my ethernet ports, enabled it and I can ping .3 now. Will have to check if IP conflicts are gone too.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, my devices keep flickering between "good internet connection" and "internet not available" status. Some devices can communicate with each other and sometimes I cannot reach other things.

Comment: Sounds like you may have cabling problems.